# Setting the observer points parameters in the table for the geodesic viewshed tool

Tags: arcgis-pro, viewshed

I am new to the geodesic viewshed tool. My project is about getting views from one point to one or many of them. I have **DEM**, **azimuth1**, **azimuth2** and I also set **observer elevation** (height). How do I set fields in the attribute table for the observer point. My results don't look good.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "my results don't look good"?

Comment: When I look on Google Earth, I can see that observer points can be viewed from that location.